# Python string to list 2D

Tags: python, string, list, matrix

I have this string:

```
[0, 0], [1, 7], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0], [9,0],
[10, 0], [11, 0], [12, 0], [13, 0], [14, 0], [15, 0], [16, 0], [17, 0], 
[18,0], [19, 0], [20, 0], [21, 0], [22, 0], [23, 0], [24, 0], [25, 0], 
[26, 0], [27, 0], [28, 0], [29, 0], [30, 0]
```

and I need to convert it in a 2D list

Can you help me?, I have tried with `string.split()`, but I can't find the correct combination.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by 2D list? something like [[0, 0], [1, 7], ... ]?

Comment: you're right Francesco

Comment: Then the answer linked by @DrHaze will do the trick. just be sure to convert the literal_eval to list since your string does not represent a valid 2D list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval` and `list` to do this:

```
import ast

s = "[0, 0], [1, 7], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0], [9,0],[10, 0], [11, 0], [12, 0], [13, 0], [14, 0], [15, 0], [16, 0], [17, 0], [18,0], [19, 0], [20, 0], [21, 0], [22, 0], [23, 0], [24, 0], [25, 0], [26, 0], [27, 0], [28, 0], [29, 0], [30, 0]"

l = list(ast.literal_eval(s))
```

Output:

```
>>> l
[[0, 0], [1, 7], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0], [9, 0], [10, 0], [11, 0], [12, 0], [13, 0], [14, 0], [15, 0], [16, 0], [17, 0], [18, 0], [19, 0], [20, 0], [21, 0], [22, 0], [23, 0], [24, 0], [25, 0], [26, 0], [27, 0], [28, 0], [29, 0], [30, 0]]
```